# Apache2 Website Encounters js error when port forwarding

Tags: web, apache2, port

I'm running into an error that I am super stuck on. My website on a non secure, http connection at the ip of the server loads find with this apache setup below. I can connect to the ip address perfectly fine, and the website loads. But when I uncomment those port forwarding lines, both the ip address and domain don't load, I get an error in the console:

p @ index-69015686.js:49

index-69015686.js:40 TypeError: t.data.slice(...).map is not a function

I have no clue what this function is referring to. I don't see how changing the apache file would cause a js error. Anyone have any ideas?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName mywebsite.com

ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com

ServerAdmin support@mywebsite.com

SetEnv SERVER_ENV production

WSGIDaemonProcess mywebsite user=bitnami threads=15 python-path=/home/bitnami/mywebsitedirectory python-home=/home/bitnami/mywebsitedirectory/venv

WSGIProcessGroup mywebsite

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/bitnami/mywebsitedirectory/mywebsite.wsgi

<Directory /home/bitnami/mywebsitedirectory>

SetEnv SERVER_ENV production

WSGIProcessGroup mywebsite

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

Require all granted

</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mywebsite.com [OR]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mywebsite.com

RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>



<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName mywebsite.com

ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com

ServerAdmin dexter.renick@gmail.com

SetEnv SERVER_ENV production

# ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/

# ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

ProxyTimeout 120

# WSGIDaemonProcess mywebsite user=bitnami threads=5 python-path=/home/bitnami/mywebsite python-home=/home/bitnami/mywebsite/venv env=SERVER_ENV=production

WSGIProcessGroup mywebsite

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/bitnami/mywebsite/mywebsite.wsgi

<Directory /home/bitnami/mywebsite>

SetEnv SERVER_ENV production

WSGIProcessGroup mywebsite

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

Require all granted

</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

</IfModule>

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem

SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem

</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

I've tried restarting my server, it works fine on my staging server. I'm super confused why this would be happening with apache changes.